# How to create dictionaries using pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, group-by

I have a dataframe containing values for several variables for each individual in different patient groups. For example, I have age, sex, weight etc. for multiple individuals in patient groups, e.g., dementia, healthy control etc. I want to ultimately create a dictionary for each group like the following:

```
{'Group': ['dementia', 'dementia', 'dementia'],
   'Age': [66, 67, 90],
   'Sex': ['M', 'M', 'F']}
```

How do I do I loop through my dataframe and create dictionaries for each? What I have so far is the beginnings of a for loop:

```
for group in df.groupby('diagnosis'):
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please post sample of your dataframe and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Assuming such a input:

```
             Group  Age Sex
0  healthy control   70   F
1         dementia   66   M
2         dementia   90   F
3  healthy control   62   M
4  healthy control   64   F
5         dementia   67   M
```

If you need the dictionary in a classical loop, just convert the group with [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
for key, group in df.groupby('Group'):
    d = group.to_dict('list')
```

Alternatively, you could use a simple dictionary comprehension to get a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
out = {k: g.to_dict('list') for k, g in df.groupby('Group')}
```

Output:

```
{'dementia': {'Age': [66, 90, 67],
              'Group': ['dementia', 'dementia', 'dementia'],
              'Sex': ['M', 'F', 'M']},
 'healthy control': {'Age': [70, 62, 64],
                     'Group': ['healthy control',
                               'healthy control',
                               'healthy control'],
                     'Sex': ['F', 'M', 'F']}}
```

Or, since the group is already present as key, dropping it from the inner dictionary:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Group'])
out = {k: g.to_dict('list') for k, g in df.groupby('Group')[cols]}
```

Output:

```
{'dementia': {'Age': [66, 90, 67], 'Sex': ['M', 'F', 'M']},
 'healthy control': {'Age': [70, 62, 64], 'Sex': ['F', 'M', 'F']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using @mozway input:

```
             Group  Age Sex
0  healthy control   70   F
1         dementia   66   M
2         dementia   90   F
3  healthy control   62   M
4  healthy control   64   F
5         dementia   67   M
```

Create a dictionary of dataframe groups using groupby.

```
df_dicts = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Group')))
```

To print each group using dictionary with Group as the key:

```
df_dicts['dementia'].to_dict('list')
```

Output:

```
{'Group': ['dementia', 'dementia', 'dementia'],
 'Age': [66, 90, 67],
 'Sex': ['M', 'F', 'M']}
```

and

```
df_dicts['healthy control'].to_dict('list')
```

Output:

```
{'Group': ['healthy control', 'healthy control', 'healthy control'],
 'Age': [70, 62, 64],
 'Sex': ['F', 'M', 'F']}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Proposed script**

```py
import pandas as pd

# create a sample dataframe
data = {'diagnosis': ['dementia', 'dementia', 'control', 'control', 'dementia'],
        'age': [66, 67, 45, 55, 90],
        'sex': ['M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create an empty dictionary to store the group dictionaries
group_dicts = {}

# loop through the groups
for name, group in df.groupby('diagnosis'):
    # create a new dictionary for the current group
    group_dict = {'Group': name}
    # extract the values of the other columns and convert to list
    for col in df.columns[1:]:
        group_dict[col] = group[col].tolist()
    # add the group dictionary to the dictionary of group dictionaries
    group_dicts[name] = group_dict

# print the resulting dictionary of dictionaries
print(group_dicts)
```

**Result**

```
{
'control': {'Group': 'control', 'age': [45, 55], 'sex': ['F', 'M']},
'dementia': {'Group': 'dementia', 'age': [66, 67, 90], 'sex': ['M', 'M', 'F']}
}
```